# Conflict window.size and some jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have a problem I cant figure out. So hope someone can help me.

I have this code in the footer of an iframe:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://sinsio.dk/iframe-resizer-master/js/iframeResizer.contentWindow.min.js" defer></script>
<script>
jQuery( ".sidebar a" ).click(function() {   
window.parentIFrame.size(1250);
jQuery('.content').css('display', 'none');
});
</script>
```

I want to resize an iframe and hide some content when clicking a link in the sidebar.

**Scenario 1 (working):**
If I only have window.parentIFrame.size(1250) in the click function it resizes the iframe.

**Scenario 2 (working):**
If i add alert(jQuery(this).attr('class')); to the function it resizes and alert the class from the clicked element. Did this to test if jQuery worked - it did.

**Scenario 3 (not working but needed):**
If I instead of the alert add jQuery('.content').css('display', 'none'); it removes the content div as i want but the resize no longer works.

Any ideas what is wrong? Doesn't make sense to me.

Kind regards,
Michael

Comment: Very hard to test and help you with this. Need more info... Provide the html for .sidebar and a, also provide what's supposed to fill out window.parentIFrame so that we can see what you are trying to achieve...

Comment: I tried using jQuery.when(function1()).then(function2()); but without luck. But that doesn't explain why the jquery alert is working at the same time as the resize but not the jquery css change.

Answer (score 0):

I had a conflict with a height attribute on the body element of the iframe. Removing this was the solution.

Thanks for taking the time to look at my post.

Kind regards,
Michael